# JPA Entity attribute names missing in generated JSON

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson

I am using JPA and and Jackson is used for generating JSON

Emp.java

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Emp.findAll", 
           query = "select o.empNo, o.empName from Emp o ") 
@Table(name = "EMP")
public class Emp implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "ename")
private String empName;

@Id
@Column(name = "empno", nullable = false)
private String empNo;
.....
```

In service class I have the following code

```
@GET
@Path("/emplist")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Object getEmployees() {
List<Emp> list = this.findAll();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
empAsJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);

public List<Emp> findAll() {
    return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Emp.findAll").getResultList();
}
```

The problem is generated JSON doesn't have attribute names, e.g.

```
["2390","JAMES"],
```

Whereas if I change namedQuery in Emp class to

```
select o  from Emp o
```

then generated JSON has attribute names as shown below

```
[{"empNo":"2390","empName":"JAMES"},
```

What could be the reason for this and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NAmed Query `select o.empNo, o.empName from Emp o` will `return List<Object[]>` where as `select o  from Emp o` will `return List<Emp>`, so accordingly `json` will be produced.

You can change the query as below

`select new Emp(o.empNo, o.empName) from Emp o` and have a constructor in your class accordingly.

or try using

`select new Map(o.empNo as empNo , o.empName as empName) from Emp o`

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the query `select o.empNo, o.empName from Emp o` you select specific entity fields and the every result row is an `Object[]`. Thus that array of the specified properties.

The second query `select o  from Emp o` selects the entire entity with all its fields, and what you see is the JSON-marashalled entity.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, your JPQL returns a `List<Object[]>`; each item in the list is an array containing the values of `o.empNo` and `o.empName`. Of course, when JSON is produced, it is produced as an array/list of items.

In the second case, you get a `List<Employee>`, which each item being an `Employee` instance, so it is serialized like an object would be (list of attribute-values).