# JPA constructor class [Emp] not found - oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EJBQLException

Tags: java, jpa, toplink, toplink-essentials

This is in continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27482835/599528)

I have namedQuery as

```
select new Emp(o.empNo, o.empName)  from Emp o
```

and constructor defined as

```
public Emp(String empNo, String empName) {
    this.empNo= empNo;
    this.empName= empName;
}
```

I am getting error when I execute

```
Exception [TOPLINK-8013] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 
(Build b52-fcs (09/24/2008))):
oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EJBQLException
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [Emp.findAll:
select new Emp(o.empNo, o.empName)  from Emp o ], line 1, column 9: 
constructor class [Emp] not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_constructor

A constructor may be used in the SELECT list to return one or more Java instances. The specified class is not required to be an entity or to be mapped to the database. **The constructor name must be fully qualified.**

```
SELECT NEW com.company.PublisherInfo(pub.id, pub.revenue, mag.price)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the error, might be useful for others.

In namedQuery instead of

```
select new Emp(o.empNo, o.empName)  from Emp o
```

provide fully qualified class name, i.e. `<packagename>.<classname>`

```
select new test.entity.Emp(o.empNo, o.empName) from Emp o
```

Thanks.

[Courtesy](https://blogs.oracle.com/adf/entry/ejb_dc_using_jpql_constructor)

Comment: we posted the same thing at the same time :)

Comment: @AdrianB. Yep, but I will give it you.