# JPA NamedQuery Select specific column and return class type

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am using JPA, I have the basic named query like this

```
@NamedQuery(name="Manifest.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM Manifest m")
```

When I call this,

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery("Manifest.getManifestInfo").getResultList()
```

I get the object back in a list like this

```
[{id:"1", name:"foo"},{id:"2", name:"bar"}]
```

But then I have another named query where I just get the names

@NamedQuery(name="Manifest.getManifestName", query="SELECT m.name FROM Manifest m")

When I run that query I get

```
[["foo"],["bar"]]
```

How can I get the second query to return the object type so its liek

```
[{name:"foo"},{name:"bar"}]
```

I made this simpler to show what I am trying to do here, the actual table has more columns but it is the same principal.

How can I return the object type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Entity attribute names missing in generated JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482835/jpa-entity-attribute-names-missing-in-generated-json)

Answer (score 0):

The feature for that use case in JPA is an [Entity Graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm).

Define it on your entity like this:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name="nameOnly", attributeNodes={
    @NamedAttributeNode("name")
})
@Entity
public class Manifest {
...
}
```

You'd leave your query itself unchanged, but apply the Entity Graph to the query before running it, either as a Load or a Fetch Graph (see link above for explanation):

```
EntityGraph<EmailMessage> eg = em.getEntityGraph("nameOnly");
entityManager.createNamedQuery("Manifest.getManifestInfo").setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", eg).getResultList()
```